# Representation of Holomorphic Functions By Exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic and nonzero on $D_{1}(0)$ the open unit disc. Can we write (for the given domain) $f(z) = e^{h(z)}$ where $h$ is holomorphic? This seems clear using a naive log argument but I'm having trouble with the issue of taking a branch of log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true on any simply connected domain.  In this case you can take $$h(z) = h(0) + \int_C \dfrac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}\ d\zeta = h(0) + \int_0^1 \dfrac{f'(tz)}{f(tz)} z\ dt $$ where $C$ is the straight line from 
$0$ to $z$ and $h(0)$ is any branch of $\log(f(0))$.

Comment: so to clarify as far as I can understand this the idea is that the value of the integral over the curve C is log(f(z)) - log(f(0))... how does this get around the issue of which branch of log is chosen? this seems equivalent to me to just defining a value of log, but I guess the argument works bc the integral of a holomorphic function is holomorphic, thus h is holomorphic? is the intuition because $e^{z}$ is a periodic function so we don't even have to take a branch, we can just define log along the branch cut and when we take $e$ to this power the resulting function is holomorphic?

Comment: The point is that $h(z)$ is an antiderivative of $f'(z)/f(z)$; on a simply-connected domain, any holomorphic function has a holomorphic antiderivative.  From this you get $(f e^{-h})' = (f' - f h') e^{-h} = 0$, so $f/e^h$ is constant.  There is no "branch cut" here: indeed, $h$ may well take different values at two points where $f$ has the same value, so it's not that we're fixing a particular branch of the logarithm and taking that function of $f(z)$.

Comment: Why do we need simply connected domain for?

Comment: @euler0.0 It's not true on domains with "holes", because you need branch cuts: e.g. $1/z$ has no holomorphic antiderivative on a deleted neighbourhood of $0$.