# Exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f:A\to \mathbb{C}$ analytic function on a convex region $A$, and f does not equal to zero in any point in $A$. Is it always true that there is such analytic function $g(z)$ 
 $$ f=e^g$$
on $A$?

Comment: Robert Israel's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/143609/16627) gives the general strategy. I suggest that you try to work this out on your own.

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer? If so, it would be great if you posted an answer containing the argument. If not, please ask what's still troubling you.

Comment: Yes, I solved it thanks, I am posting answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a function $f'(z)/f(z)$, by given assumptions it is analytic on convex region, so it has analytic  primitive $F(z)$. Let $h(z)=f(z)^{-F(z)}$. Then we find that $h'=0$ on $A$. So $h$ equals to some nonzero constant,
$$ fe^{-F}=c$$ Let $a\in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $e^a=c$, so we got that
$$f=e^{F+a}$$
and $F+a$ is analytic function.

Comment: Very good. Observe that $f'/f$ formally looks like the derivative of $\log{f}$ (it's called the [logarithmic derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative)), so there's no surprise that its primitive $F$ does what it does...

Answer (score 2):

Note: this answer an earlier version of the question.

No. If $A$ is multiply connected then there is no such a $g$.

EDIT: after the edit of the question, then yes there must exist $g$ such that $f=e^g$.