# Can we find holomorphic $ g $ such that $ e^{g}=f $ for holomorphic $ f $ which never vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $ f $ is holomorphic function and $f(z)\neq 0 $ for all $z\in \mathbb{C} $.

Is it true that there sxists $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C} $ such that $e^g=f$ ?

I know that the answer is no, but I cannot prove it. I tried to assume that there is such a function $ g $ for any holomorphic $ f$, such that $f(z) \neq 0 $. Thus, $g$ has to be $\log(f) $ which should be defined on the whole plane (I think here we should have a contradiction).

How can I show the contradiction? the only way I know to show that $\log $ cannot be defined on the whole plane is by showing that $ \intop_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}\neq1 $. If I knew that there exists a path $\gamma(t) $ such that $ f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right) $ is a circle around the origin, I could claim that $ \intop_{\gamma}\frac{f'}{f}=\intop_{f\left(\gamma\right)}\frac{1}{z}\neq0 $.

But how can I make sure such $\gamma $ exists?

(Im pretty sure my idea dose not lead anywhere). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ummm the answer is yes there is such a $g$. The integral (of $f'/f$) is 0 by Cauchy's theorem

Comment: "I know that the answer is no" Then what about $g=z$ for the case $f=e^z$?

Comment: @Winther I did not write that there are no $ f $ which satisfies this condition, I wrote that I think it is false for all the holomorphic functions...

Comment: @peek-a-boo Does it mean that we can define $\log(f) $ on the whole plane for entire functions which not vanish? I thought it would be a problem since $\log $ is multi valued

Comment: $\log $ (i.e an inverse function for the exponential) itself cannot be defined on the whole punctured plane, but that doesn't say anything about the existence/non-existence of $g$. Just show the integral of $f'/f$ over every loop vanishes and thus it has a primitive function. That is the desired $g$ (up to a constant)

Comment: Anyway: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223432/exponential-function?noredirect=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143609/representation-of-holomorphic-functions-by-exponential