# existence of primitive - diff. of log function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this homework problem which i need your help about how to start?

g is holomorphic in a simply connected domain U. show that there is a f which is holomorphic in U without zero such that g=f'/f in U.

I know that for any simply connected domain U if g is holomorphic in U then g has a primitive in U i.e. f'=g. and i should use this somehow but I could not see it how?

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $f'/f$ is the derivative of $\log f$.

Comment: @gerry: I saw that I guess you somehow see that g is a branch of logz in U but i do not can you please give more hint.

Comment: I think the question of defining a branch of $\log f$ in a domain where $f$ is never zero has been asked on this site recently. Maybe question 3736.

Comment: Actually, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74920/the-existence-of-analytical-branch-of-the-logarithm-of-a-holomorphic-function --- also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143609/representation-of-holomorphic-functions-by-exponential

Comment: @gerry: firstly thanks a lot for all the links. but in my case a holomorphic function g defined on U might be vanished or not it is not said anything about it on the contrary of the other question

Comment: What's relevant is $f$ not being zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it goes like this.

$g$ is holomorphic, so it has a holomorphic antiderivative, $h$.

$h$ is holomorphic, so $e^h$ is holomorphic and nonzero. Let $f=e^h$, and show it's what you want.

Comment: yes, I thought the same way. thnks for all the answer.